# CORP Blocking an Obviously Same-Origin Request with CSP sandbox Set

Tags: http, content-security-policy, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

Imagine a site with two documents: `index.html` and `test.jpg`, both located at the root. `index.html` has the following content.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
        <head>
                <meta charset=utf-8>
                <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=content-type>
                <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <p>Hello.</p>
                <img src="/test.jpg">
        </body>
</html>
```

If served with no security headers, this works just fine. However, with these headers on `index.html`:

```
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

and this header on `test.jpg`:

```
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-origin
```

`test.jpg` will no longer be loaded by Chrome 98. It reports `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin 200` in the console.

Adding the following header to `index.html` will cause the image to be blocked by Firefox 97 as well:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; prefetch-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; form-action 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content; disown-opener; sandbox; base-uri 'none'
```

(I'm aware that that's a lot of directives, but I tried to bisect them to what was important and couldn't figure it out.)

What is happening here? `https://example.com` and `https://example.com/test.jpg` are the same origin, aren't they? Explicitly navigating to `https://example.com/index.html` also blocks the loading of `test.jpg`. What is missing from my understanding of same-origin? Why is there a difference between Chrome and Firefox's handling? Why does adding CSP cause Firefox to start blocking the requests for `test.jpg`?

In case I missed something, here are the complete set of headers for each request (from cURL):

```
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.77.0
> accept: */*
>
< HTTP/2 200
< date: Wed, 16 Feb 2022 04:56:43 GMT
< server: Apache
< via: e3s
< last-modified: Wed, 16 Feb 2022 04:43:18 GMT
< content-length: 226
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< referrer-policy: same-origin
< content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; prefetch-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; form-action 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content; disown-opener; sandbox; base-uri 'none'
< cross-origin-embedder-policy: require-corp
< cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
< etag: "e2-5d81b49ddfad8"
< accept-ranges: bytes
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
```

```
> GET /test.jpg HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.77.0
> accept: */*
>
< HTTP/2 200
< date: Wed, 16 Feb 2022 04:52:19 GMT
< server: Apache
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< referrer-policy: same-origin
< cross-origin-resource-policy: same-origin
< last-modified: Wed, 16 Feb 2022 04:22:59 GMT
< etag: "18692-5d81b013bbe82"
< accept-ranges: bytes
< content-length: 99986
< cache-control: public, max-age=31557600, immutable
< age: 336
< via: e2s
< content-type: image/jpeg
<
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tried to reproduce, but from reading this it would make sense for Firefox to start blocking as you sandboxed the document, meaning it has an opaque origin and therefore the image will appear cross-origin.

As for Chrome, could sandboxing have been in effect there too somehow?

Comment: This was correct! Changing to `sandbox allow-same-origin;` in the CSP header solved this problem in both FF and Chrome. I'm not sure what I was seeing in Chrome with it sometimes working; perhaps it was some cached behavior.